# How should I go about testing a monolithic executable package?

Tags: haskell, testing, automated-tests, cabal

I have a monolithic `executable` package with several modules. *(What I mean by "monolithic" is that it only has one clause in its `cabal` file, and that is `executable`.)* It is currently tested with shell scripts, in a black box manner. I thought I would like to write unit tests for some individual functions, but `cabal` does not agree:

```
% cabal new-test
cabal: Cannot test the package x-0.0.0.0 because none of the
components are available to build: the test suite 'x-test' is not
available because the solver did not find a plan that included the test suites
```

Here are the relevant sections of `package.cabal`:

```
executable x
  ...
  other-modules: ...
  ...

test-suite x-test
    type: exitcode-stdio-1.0
    main-is: Test.hs
    build-depends: base, x
    hs-source-dirs: test
```

My understanding is that I should move as many modules as possible to an internal library, which would make it possible for the test suite to depend on them. However, I am not sure the maintainers will approve of such radical change. Is there a less invasive way?

My other concern is that, insofar as `Main.hs` is in the `executable x` clause, and we cannot import that into `x-test`, the functions therein (at the very least `main`) will be unavailable for testing. How should I go about testing these functions then, beside shell scripts?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's completely okay to move modules to `library` stanza (or internal library stanza  if you don't want to expose those modules).

> How should I go about testing it, beside shell scripts?

There's a common practice in Haskell world to move everything (even `main` function) into `library` so your `Main.hs` would look like this:

```
module Main where

import MyLib as Lib (main)

main :: IO ()
main = Lib.main
```

With this approach you can test completely everything via Haskell unit testing libraries.

> However, I am not sure the maintainers will approve of such radical change. Is there a less invasive way?

Well, if maintainers care about their package, they should agree to this refactoring if they want better testing.

Comment: By chance you know of examples of moving `main` to library in a more or less well known package?

Comment: @IgnatInsarov I'm aware of this library: https://github.com/kowainik/summoner/blob/master/app/Main.hs I often saw similar packages (with `main` in library) but can't think of another example from top of my head.

Comment: @IgnatInsarov `pandoc` is an example. The executable is https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/blob/master/pandoc.hs but it delegates everything to the `Text.Pandoc.App` module http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pandoc-2.2.1/docs/Text-Pandoc-App.html

Answer (score 6):

If moving the packages to a (perhaps internal) library is not an option, you could simply add all the sources of the executable to the `hs-source-dirs` of the test suite, and also add the dependencies of the executable to the `build-depends` of the test suite.

This has the disadvantage that you'll compile the same files twice: once for the executable and once for the test suite.

Comment: But I will then end up with two modules named Main, right?

Comment: @IgnatInsarov In your question you mention that `Main` should not be exposed to the test suite, so better not to include it.

Comment: My phrasing was unclear. That Main is not exposed is not a requirement, it is merely what I thought of as a limitation of Cabal format.

Comment: By the way, does this actually happen in the wild? Can you think of an example amongst more or less widely known packages?

Comment: @IgnatInsarov I can't recall an example.